Output to file from .bashrc does not work
I want to make a greeting on my Linux server for users when they log in. The server has a tsp task spooler for organizing a task queue, and I want the current task queue to be shown when connecting. If I simply insert the tsp command into /etc/bash.bashrc at the beginning of the file, then instead of displaying a list of tasks, only the queue header is displayed:
ID State Output E-Level Times(r/u/s) Command [run=0/1]
But there is no task list itself. I went the other way and wrote a microscript that does this separately:
tsp > /mnt/d/shared/tsp/tsp_list.txt
echo "Job list:"
cat /mnt/d/shared/tsp/tsp_list.txt

If I just run this script from the console, everything works, but if it is launched when I log in from bashrc, then the script runs, but again only the header is written to tsp_list.txt. What could this be connected with?
At first I thought that there might be problems with access rights (???) and moved everything to a directory where all users have access (/mnt/d/shared/). But the problem persisted.
Update: For some reason this only happens during the login to the server. When switch user from console everything works as it should...

Please edit the question and add the version and type of Ubuntu you are using.

This looks very much like something specific to this tsp program which may depend on some initialization, environment or the like. If this is not a program distributed with Ubuntu you might be better off asking its manufacturer/author for help.

According to this manpage, tsp expects to find the queue socket first in a location specified by the TMPDIR environment variable - so perhaps something in the login process is setting that?
